# Como ejecutar una pagina?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm, react-redux

hice un git clone de mi repositorio que subi desde otra PC y me lo baje a una nueva PC que tengo.
cuando intento correr el la pagina con npm start o npm run dev me tira este error...
como lo soluciono?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tú en este momento te encuentras situado en la carpeta padre (RIck-And-Morty) dentro de tu consola, lo que pasa es que tu proyecto está subdividido en dos carpetas (Client y Server). para que el comando te funcione debes cambiarte de directorio digitando en esa misma consola `cd Client` que es donde se puede ejecutar tu proyecto, luego digita el comando `npm run start` y notarás que ya te funciona.